# Debug weird "bvar is busy" logs that (perhaps) makes FastAPI server not responding

Tags: python, pytorch, fastapi

I've tried to build an API application based on FastAPI to process some requests using AI models (Pytorch and Paddle framework).

Sometimes, I see those logs appearing continuously in the console. And at that time, I cannot reach any end-points anymore (response time out error). The only thing I can do is to restart the server and everything back to normal.

I don't know how to reproduce this error and have no idea where it came from.

How can I debug it? And which extra information that I need to provide for a closer view on this problem?

```
| W0308 23:13:21.249563    40 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!                                                                        
| W0308 23:13:27.000713    40 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!                                                                        
| W0308 23:13:31.084384    87 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!                                                                        
| W0308 23:13:32.490388    40 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!                                                                        
| W0308 23:13:40.359278    87 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!                                                                        
| W0308 23:13:41.317720    40 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!                                                                        
| W0308 23:13:48.468175    87 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!
| W0308 23:13:52.974829    40 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!
| W0308 23:14:04.213120    40 sampler.cpp:139] bvar is busy at sampling for 2 seconds!
```

Comment: https://github.com/apache/incubator-brpc/issues/1383

Comment: @DanielF I saw that before, but I'm not sure "bvar" will be responsible for the "not responding" issue on FastAPI.

Comment: If the code handling bvar gets stuck, there's not much that FastAPI can do if it doesn't get any time to do it. You might want to run FastAPI in multiple processes if you foresee that one of your processes will spend most of its time in cpu bound processing.